# How to change default Bucket in app.config

Tags: c#, couchbase

My App.Config looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="couchbaseClients">
      <section name="couchbase"
               type="Couchbase.Configuration.Client.Providers.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase.NetClient"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <couchbaseClients>
    <couchbase useSsl="false">
      <servers>
        <add uri="http://localhost:8091/pools"></add>
      </servers>
      <buckets>
        <add name="CBMigration" useSsl="false">
          <connectionPool name="custom" maxSize="10" minSize="5"></connectionPool>
        </add>
      </buckets>
    </couchbase>
  </couchbaseClients>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In that i given bucket name is "CBMigration" but still the entries are in default bucket only.
And my c# code for initializing cluster is `_instance = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase");`

I need to make the bucket as "CBMigration" for the Cluster i initialized using the app.config.

Where i am going wrong ?
Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a gap in documentation there. The bucket entries in  are only used to provide customized defaults for the bucket's configuration. That is the use of ssl, connection pool tuning, etc...

But having just one bucket config entry like that doesn't actually change the behavior of `OpenBucket()`: the default bucket used by the client is always "default".

You still have to explicitly open the specific bucket you want, using `OpenBucket(BucketName, BucketPassword)`... It's just that once you do that, said bucket will be opened using tuning parameters found in its corresponding section in App.config instead of hardcoded default ones.

Does that make sense?